# PHP svn , svn_add not working on linux/ubuntu

Tags: php, svn

I am working in SVN PHP library, when i try to use svn_add it shows the following error

Warning: svn_add(): svn error(s) occured 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory) '/var/www/myrepo' is not a working copy in /var/www/test/test.php on line 7

also tried svn_checkout, svn_cat etc etc
I have complete svn repository setup on the my local machine and i am passing the following URL '/var/www/repo/'.

Here is the my code

$path = '/var/www/myrepo/';
svn_add($path.'test.txt');

tried its http URL as well, it works well with Rabbit VCS SVN and performing all operations with the same URL.

Please suggest any solution.

Here is the link to phpsvn : http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from the manual:

> svn_add — Schedules the addition of an item in a working directory

you have to be in the working directory of the repo.
Before calling `svn_add`, do a `chdir($path)`